# SQL with left outer join and 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to add an ADD at the end of my code. Please have a look on my code and thanks for your support:

```
SELECT Area.org, 
   Supervisors.NomSup, 
   Supervisors.PrenomSup, 
   Employees.NomEmp, 
   Employees.PrenomEmp, 
   Employees.NoIdAlcanEmp, 
   Competencies.CodeCompetencies, 
   Competencies.CompetencyName, 
   LinkResultComp.AssNote, 
   LinkResultComp.AssDate
FROM ((((((
       Area INNER JOIN Supervisors ON Area.IdArea = Supervisors.IdArea
      )
      INNER JOIN Employees ON Supervisors.IdSupervisor = Employees.IdSupervisor
     )
     INNER JOIN LinkProfilesEmployees ON Employees.IdEmp = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdEmp
    )
    INNER JOIN Profiles ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfilesEmployees.IdProfiles
   )
   INNER JOIN LinkProfComp ON Profiles.IdProfiles = LinkProfComp.IdProfiles
  )
  INNER JOIN Competencies ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkProfComp.IdCompetencies
 )
 LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies AND ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)

WHERE Area.org LIKE "*20*" AND Competencies.CodeCompetencies LIKE "khse2010-05"
ORDER BY Supervisors.NomSup, Employees.NomEmp;
```

Comment: WTH does "I would like to add an ADD at the end of my code" mean?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies AND ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the extra `ON` that you added

So change this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp 
ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies 
  AND ON Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)
------^^ This one
```

to this

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN LinkResultComp 
ON (Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies 
  AND Competencies.IdCompetencies = LinkResultComp.IdCompetencies)
```

Of course I assume you meant different fields for the second condition